# How can I splice in a type and a default value in Scala quasiquotes?

Tags: scala, scala-macros, scala-quasiquotes

I'm trying to make a type-provider that gives updated case classes.

How might I splice in a type and a default value (or omit the default value)?

```
def impl(c: Context)(annottees: c.Expr[Any]*): c.Expr[Any] = {
    import c.universe._
    import Flag._

    val result = {
      annottees.map(_.tree).toList match {
        case q"$mods class $name[..$tparams](..$first)(...$rest) extends ..$parents { $self => ..$body }" :: Nil =>
          val valType    = //TODO
          val valDefault = //TODO
          val helloVal   = q"""val x: $valType = $valDefault"""
          q"$mods class $name[..$tparams](..$first, $helloVal)(...$rest) extends ..$parents { $self => ..$body }"
      }
    }
    c.Expr[Any](result)
  }
```

#### I've tried:

I've tried simply `val valType = q"String"`, but then I get an error as if a default value was not found: `not enough arguments for method apply`

I've also tried splicing in a val defined as `typeOf[String]`, and I've also tried splicing lists of `ValDef`s into my `q"$mods class...` (like I've seen done into a `q"def...` in some similar questions on this site), but in each case there is a [typer error](https://gist.github.com/julianpeeters/8367976).

Any tips? Thanks very much for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `tq` interpolator in the definition of `valType` to create the type tree.

The rest is a little trickier. It seems to work just fine if you define the extra parameter directly:

```
q"""
  $mods class $name[..$tparams](
    ..$first,
    val x: $valType = $valDefault
  )(...$rest) extends ..$parents { $self => ..$body }
"""
```

But when you define `$helloVal` and then plug that in you end up without the default parameter flag. You could write a helper like this:

```
def makeDefault(valDef: ValDef) = valDef match {
  case ValDef(mods, name, tpt, rhs) => ValDef(
    Modifiers(
      mods.flags | DEFAULTPARAM, mods.privateWithin, mods.annotations
    ),
    name, tpt, rhs
  )
}
```

Now you can write the following:

```
val valType    = tq"String"
val valDefault = q""""foo""""
val helloVal   = makeDefault(q"val x: $valType = $valDefault")
```

And everything should work as expected.

Comment: Latest quasiquotes set DEFAULTPARAM & PARAM flags for you so that you can just splice val defs without any preprocessing.

Comment: Looks like I still need preprocessing in Scala 2.10.3 with paradise 2.0.0-M2 ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/julianpeeters/8404968)). Isn't that the latest version? cc @DenShabalin

Comment: It's the latest version of the plugin but it's behind 2.11 master. Unfortunately I don't have time for paradise plugin atm. There is a plan to backport latest features some time around 2.11 release.